# advertencia al corre el comando bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

acabo de instalar Rails en su versión 5.1 y al crear un proyecto nuevo y corre el comando bundle install me nuestra el siguiente mensaje.

**The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.**

Comment: Podrías agregar tu `Gemfile`?

Answer (score 2):

El mensaje es inofensivo y puedes ignorarlo; de hecho se muestra porque seguramente no estás utilizando windows, sin embargo tu `Gemfile` tiene la línea tal como la muestra Vicente en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74480/42433) (rails la agrega por defecto):

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

El objetivo de esa línea es incluir la gema [`tzinfo-data`](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo) en windows, misma que se utiliza para obtener información sobre zonas horarias.

Si aún así deseas eliminar el mensaje, simplemente elimina la opción `platforms`:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data'
```

y ejecuta `bundle update`.

O bien, la puedes eliminar por completo, pero considera que te generará error si llegas a ejecutar tu aplicación en Windows.

Answer (score 1):

en el fichero Gemfile de tu app mira a ver si donde lo tienes referenciado aparece algo como esto:

```
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

si no, ponlo asi en caso de que estes usando windows